# Using macro in notepad++ for creating sql script

Tags: sql, macros, notepad++

I have a sql script that looks like

```
UPDATE dbo.Pictures 

SET Data = 

(SELECT data 

FROM [SRV-Data].[QAFull-Global].dbo.Pictures p

WHERE p.PictureID = '')

WHERE PictureID = ''



UPDATE dbo.Pictures 

SET ThumbnailData = 

(SELECT ThumbnailData 

FROM [SRV-Data].[QAFull-Global].dbo.Pictures p

WHERE p.PictureID = '')

WHERE PictureID = ''
```

And about 2000 Unique IDs. I think you guys understand the rest. I want notepad++ to go throgh and fill in the '' with the list of id's i have to run it in management studio. Thanks for any help.

List of ID's a few ID's

```
7E26E0DC-5B51-4A63-95E7-0FE6168AD217

377C9BF5-59B9-43B4-9BDB-1092BEDF3A68

454047DD-A045-451B-B1C6-109EB59B1871

7734C4B0-5F80-4D45-B8C3-14C0F5D029FD

4FC6C36C-8B35-498D-970C-15078B331857

548E09B5-A339-4DCA-9DDA-151D95C24DBA

B6399FAA-03A9-410C-84B6-155C807DD03F

895A8101-D028-4935-B447-156E4C936E65

62D7610A-3ABD-44CD-91CE-16936A275DCC

EA7D5104-5647-449F-B91F-16ADBE7AA057
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your list of unique IDs already stored in a database?  If so, I would suggest instead of using notepad++ to create a macro, I would create a select statement that returns a list of the update statements that you're looking for.

Honestly, even if the Unique IDs aren't currently in the database, I would go through the trouble of importing them, and then creating your select statement.

```
SELECT
    '
        UPDATE dbo.Pictures 
        SET Data = 
        (
            SELECT data 
            FROM [SRV-Data].[QAFull-Global].dbo.Pictures p
            WHERE p.PictureID = ''' + sourceTable.PictureID + '''
        )
        WHERE PictureID = ''' + sourceTable.PictureID + ''
FROM
    WhateverTableHasYourUniqueIDs sourceTable
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want what I think you want, just use the recording feature in Notepad++. Put the cursor at the start of the first ID, hit "Macro->Start Recording", add a quote, hit "end" to get to the end of the line, hit another quote, and I'm guessing a comma, move one line down and hit "home" to get to the beginning of the line. Then hit "Macro->Stop Recording".

That's now captured a macro that wraps the current line's ID in quotes and moves to the beginning of the next line. Hit "Macro->Run a Macro Multiple Time", choose "Run until the end of file".

Even if that's not exactly what you want, hopefully it'll give you an idea. Basically, record "start at the beginning of one line, do the operation for that one line, move to the beginning of the next line", and then play back.